# Sending data from Windows Mobile to a Windows WCF

Tags: wcf, silverlight, windows-mobile

I'm not knowledgeable in the whole "server-side" idea. Right now, I just want to start learning how to send data from a windows mobile phone application to a server.

I'm pretty good at C# and making apps. I just need to learn how to send data from and to a server/mobile application.

I am using Silverlight (The latest one) as the API for my windows phone app. At the moment, a "hello world" sort of program would be awesome.

Any help is is extremely appreciated!

Subby~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple. Just a bing/google search would have lead you to the answer. For sake of brevity here's an article that describes each step in detail

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/UrmimalaPal/creating-a-windows-phone-7-application-consuming-data-using-a-wcf-service/

Let me know if you want to know in specific or you are stuck somewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! I'm going to try and implement what's being mentioned in the tutorial which you've provided. I'll let you know how it went!